# What is the proper way of saying Takbir for Eid?

Tags: salat, sunnah, jamaat, eid, takbir

I could see the takbir in all masjids, so I think it wouldn't be an innovation.

But, I would like to know,

- What is the proper way of saying these Takbirs for Eid?
- In my masjid, they are saying Takbir after every prayer for three to
  four days after Eid. Is it correct?
- Does the rules for saying Takbir is same for both Eids?
- What should I do if I miss the Jamaath? Should I say Takbir alone?

Comment: I'm thinking a "which is correct" is not appropriate; it pits one group against another.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones it seems to me that at least sunnis have a consensus on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying takbeer is authentic in Bakrid (not in eid ul fitr) after each prayer until fourth day including asr and should not be done after maghrib on the fourth day.  If you missed the jamah prayer, you can say alone silently.